# Averaging vectors in Pyspark with lookup table

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to implement a simple Doc2Vec algorithm in PySpark using a pre-trained GloVe model from https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/.

I have two RDDs:

- A pair RDD called `documents` in the form (K:[V]) where K is the document ID, and [V] is a list of all the words in that document, for example 

  `('testDoc1':'i am using spark')
  ('testDoc2':'testing spark')`
- A pair RDD called `words` representing the word embeddings in the form K:V where K is a word and V is the vector that represents the word, for example 

  `('i',       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
  ('spark':   [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]) 
  ('am',      [0.3, 0.3, 0.3])
  ('testing', [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
  ('using',   [0.4, 0.4, 0.4])`

What is the correct way to iterate through the words in `documents` to get an average vector sum for all of the words? In the above example, the end result would look like:

`('testDoc1':[0.25, 0.25, 0.25])
('testDoc2':[0.35, 0.35, 0.35])`

Comment: Want to make sure I am not misunderstanding something: is your average vector sum for testDoc1 correct?
Should it be... `('testDoc1':[0.25, 0.25, 0.25])`

i.e. `0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3 + 0.4 / 4` = `0.25`

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a function `tokenize` that transforms the strings to a list of words. Then you can `flatMap` `documents` to get an `RDD` of tuples `(word, document id)`:

```
flattened_docs = documents.flatMap(lambda x: [(word, x[0]) for word in tokenize(x[1])])
```

Then joining with `words` will give you `(word, (document id, vector))` tuples, and you can drop the words at this point:

```
doc_vectors = flattened_docs.join(words).values
```

Note that this is an inner join, so you're throwing away an words that do not have embeddings. Since you presumably want to count those words in your average, a left join is likely more appropriate and you'll then have to replace any resulting `None`s with the zero vector (or whatever vector of your choice).

We can group by document id to get an rdd of `(document id, [list of vectors])` and then average (I'll assume you have a function called `average`).

```
final_vectors = doc_vectors.groupByKey().mapValues(average)
```

(Please excuse my Scala-influenced Python. It's been a while since I've used pyspark and I haven't checked if it's `flatMap` or `flat_map` and so on.)